# c# - How to assign resources folder to a string

Tags: c#, string, resources, location

I'm currently using this,

```
string finename = "text.txt"; //setting file name

//setting locations
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string filepath = @"C:\User\Users\Documents\Files\Apple"; // <--- need to use Resources folder in the project folder here


//filename and location combining to be copied
string source = Path.Combine(filepath,filename);
string destination = Path.Combine(path,filename);

if (something=1)
{ 
    File.Copy(source,destination, true); //copying
}
```

I've added all the files to the Resources now i need to refer to Resources folder instead of "filepath" here, 
is there any way to assign the resources folder (& its contents) to a string so i can simply change the location? then i can use this code on other PC's also.

Edit -

Imagine i have orange,mango and apple folder inside the resource folder, and each of these 3 folders contain a text file with the name "text.txt".

And i need to copy one of these text files from each & every fruit folder on request & paste it on desktop.

Now i need to store the location of "Resources\apple" , "Resources\orange" & "Resources\mango" on 3 different strings so i can simply call them in the "string source = Path.Combine(filepath,filename)" part instead of older "filepath" to copy those text files from any of the fruit folder inside resources folder to the desktop.

thanks.

Comment: Is your Resource folder present in your projects current directory? or straight forward question where is your resource folder?

Comment: yes, it is present in my current directory of the Project.

Comment: So you can use `string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Resources")` to get your resource directory path.

Comment: i tried it, 
when i put 
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Resources\apple");
its giving me error at "\"apple;

Comment: When I put...? what next..? You are accessing file, right? you need to give extension as well. Are u giving extension in second parameter of Combine function

Comment: i need to store the location of a folder inside the Resources folder in my project. As "filepath" to replace its location with the folder location in resources, as u can see from the above code it points to a folder not a file.

Comment: Ohh my mistake, but I notice your declaration variable of **`finename`**. It should be **filename**

Comment: That is not how resources are handled in .NET. What you are after is called *Satellite Assembly*. This will be an assembly that contains your resources and then your application can load them from any location. Read [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2005/01/01/Make-the-Best-of-NET-Resource-Files.aspx?Page=2) or google *Satellite Assemblies*.

Comment: @L.Ethan I just edited my code, Look at it. I hope it will work. Please let me know if it does't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get `src or root` folder path.
2. Combine root folder path with your resource folder path.
3. Combine result(root\resources) with your file name

Here you go, you will get exact path of file and now you can copy it to the destination.

Here is the implementation: This code is running on my machine.

```
/// <summary>
/// Here you just need to send fruit name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fruitName">Name of fruit</param>
public void CopyFile(string fruitName)
{
    string filename = "text.txt"; //setting file name
    string resouceFolderName = Path.Combine("Resources", fruitName);
    //Destination Path
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    //CurrentDirectory return src\\Bin\\Debug so extracting src root folder path
    string parentFolderPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName).FullName;
    //combining parent folder path with resource folder name
    string folderPath = Path.Combine(parentFolderPath, resouceFolderName); // <--- need to use Resources folder in the project folder here

    //Checking if exist or not
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath) || !Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        return;
    }

    //filename and location combining to be copied
    string source = Path.Combine(folderPath, filename);
    string destination = Path.Combine(path, filename);

    if (true)
    {
        File.Copy(source, destination, true); //copying
    }
}
```

**Note:** Here I used **test.txt** and  **Resources** string as a constant considering they won't change

Comment: well, this worked. I just defined the folder names as strings and passed them to the fruitName string from your code! And marked your answer as the solution too. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

What you are doing here is retrieving the path to your desktop and copying your .txt file from your filepath to there. 
You are not copying the file onto your project "Resources" folder.

In case your file is there as @Prasad telkikar said, with the following code you would have the path to your's "Resource" folder and be able to access all the content inside it.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Resources");
```

Comment: CurrentDirectory will give path of Bin folder, but resource folder is present in location where csproj file is exist, your code will give output as \\bin\\Debug\\Resource which is not exist..Am I right?

Comment: Imagine i have orange,mango and apple folder inside the resource folder, and each of these 3 folders contain a text file with the name "text.txt". & i need to copy these text files from each & every fruit folder on request & paste it on desktop. Now i need to store the location of "Resources\apple" , "Resources\orange" & "Resources\mango" on 3 different strings so i can simply call them in the 
 "string source = Path.Combine(filepath,filename)" part instead of older "filepath" to copy those text files from any of the fruit folder inside resources folder to the desktop.